# writing array in struct (Golang)

Tags: arrays, go, struct

I have been writing test cases using "testing" package of Golang. And I've come across a situation where I have to write array and function pointers into a table.

I tried following:

```
type myFunctionType func( []float64, []float64 ) float64
var testMatrix = []struct {
    dataX []float64
    dataY []float64
    result float64
    myFunction myFunctionType
} {
{ {2, 3}, {8, 7}, 1, doMagicOne},
  {2, 3}, {8, 7}, 1, doMagicTwo},
}
```

But every time I end up getting following error or something else:

> missing type in composite literal

Any input in the above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are reporting is caused by the lack of a declaration of type before the arrays in your array. The error:

> missing type in composite literal

Is referring to this bit of your declaration:

```
{2, 3}
```

That needs to specify the type of the array:

```
[]float64{2, 3}
```

So you need:

```
var testMatrix = []struct {
    dataX      []float64
    dataY      []float64
    result     float64
    myFunction myFunctionType
}{
    {[]float64{2, 3}, []float64{8, 7}, 1, doMagicOne},
    {[]float64{2, 3}, []float64{8, 7}, 1, doMagicTwo},
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/AguxDJ11HS

Comment: Kenny, Thanks for the answer. I have been trying []float({1,2}) , and thinking whats wrong!